# Build XMLDocument in C#.Net

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

HI I Need to Build a XML like Below and convert it to a String

Values in the XML will be changing dynamically.

any suggestion?

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Message release='001' version='008' xmlns='http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT'>
  <Header>
    <To Qualifier='ZZZ'>xxxxxxx</To>
    <From Qualifier='ZZZ'>xxxxxxx</From>
    <MessageID>xxxxxx</MessageID>
    <SentTime>2002-09-30T08:15:22</SentTime>
    <Security>
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username/>
      </UsernameToken>
      <Sender>
        <SecondaryIdentification>xxxxxxxxx</SecondaryIdentification>
      </Sender>
      <Receiver>
        <SecondaryIdentification>xxxxxxxxxxx</SecondaryIdentification>
      </Receiver>
    </Security>
    <TestMessage>1</TestMessage>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <RxHistoryRequest>
      <RxReferenceNumber>POCDH1</RxReferenceNumber>
      <Prescriber>
        <Identification>
          <NPI>xxxxxxx</NPI>
          <DEANumber>xxxxxxxx</DEANumber>
        </Identification>
        <Name>
          <LastName>JONES</LastName>
          <FirstName>MARK</FirstName>
        </Name>
        <PhoneNumbers>
          <Phone>
            <Number>6152219800</Number>
            <Qualifier>TE</Qualifier>
          </Phone>
        </PhoneNumbers>
      </Prescriber>
      <Patient>
        <PatientRelationship>1</PatientRelationship>
        <Name>
          <LastName>PALTROW</LastName>
          <FirstName>BRUCE</FirstName>
          <MiddleName>K</MiddleName>
        </Name>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <DateOfBirth>1954-12-25</DateOfBirth>
      </Patient>
      <BenefitsCoordination>
        <PayerIdentification>
          <PayerID>PBM123</PayerID>
        </PayerIdentification>
        <PayerName>INSURANCE COMPANY NAME</PayerName>
        <CardholderID>MEMBERID</CardholderID>
        <CardholderName>PALTROW, BRUCE</CardholderName>
        <GroupID>B000000</GroupID>
        <Consent>Y</Consent>
        <PBMMemberID>B000000%111111110%001</PBMMemberID>
      </BenefitsCoordination>
    </RxHistoryRequest>
  </Body>
</Message>
```

I tried something like this

Creating Serializable classes

```
[Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Message", Namespace = "http://www.domain.com/messaging")]
    public class RxHistoryRequest
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string version = string.Empty;
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string release = string.Empty;
        [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
        public string xsiSchemaLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Namespace"] + " " +
                                          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SS_DirectorySchema"]; 
        public Header Header = new Header();
        public RxHistory Body = new RxHistory();
    }
//rest of the Properties in the classes
```

And in my Method

```
RxHistoryRequest RxHReq = new RxHistoryRequest();
        RxHReq.version = "008"; //ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSversion"];  
        RxHReq.release = "001"; //ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSrelease"];
//declare values to the rest of the Properties 
//then


MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RxHistoryRequest));
            xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, RxHReq);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("messaging","http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT");
            //ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SurescriptsNamespace"]


            memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] data =  memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Some where it is turning right as i need.

Comment: There are lots of built-in classes for generating and manipulating XML data with .NET, and the documentation is fairly extensive and intuitive.  What part exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @JonSkeet please see the updated question with the status

Comment: You have a good start.  What are you having trouble with?  Are you getting errors?  Is it not flexible enough for your schema?

Comment: @HaBo: Have you considered just building it with LINQ to XML instead or using serialization?

Comment: Generated Schema is not machining with the raw XML. Wondering if there is any better way of achieving it. If this is the best way of doing it, then i will continue...

Comment: @JonSkeet yes i love to do it that way. But I have no clue where to star with using Linq to XML

Comment: @HaBo: Have you searched for "LINQ to XML Tutorial" or looked on MSDN? There's *loads* of information available.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you that was quite easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with @JonSkeet suggestion i flipped my idea to Linq-to-XML
that has made my work quite easy.

if any one would be interested to know working on Linq-to-XML,
here is my Code.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT";
        XElement xml = new XElement(ns + "Message",
            new XAttribute("release", "001"),
            new XAttribute("version", "008"),
            new XElement(ns + "Header",
                new XElement(ns + "To",
                    new XAttribute("Qualifier", "ZZZ"), "xxxxxxxxxx"),
                new XElement(ns + "From",
                    new XAttribute("Qualifier", "ZZZ"), "xxxxxxxxxxxx"),
                    new XElement(ns + "MessageID", CommonController.GetIntegerGUID().ToString()),
                    new XElement(ns + "SentTime", "2002-09-30T08:15:22"),
                    new XElement(ns + "Security",
                        new XElement(ns + "UsernameToken",
                            new XElement(ns + "Username", "")),
                            new XElement(ns + "Sender",
                                new XElement(ns + "SecondaryIdentification", "PASSWORD")),
                                new XElement(ns + "Receiver",
                                    new XElement(ns + "SecondaryIdentification", "RXHUB"))
                        ),
                        new XElement(ns + "TestMessage", "1")
                        ),
                        new XElement(ns + "Body",
                            new XElement(ns + "RxHistoryRequest",
                                new XElement(ns + "RxReferenceNumber", "POCDH1"),

// it goes on like that
```

Hope this will be useful for some one.